# Menu toggle with options inside using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a menu with options inside. I'm using only CSS with `checkbox` and `radio` inputs.

By changing one of the options, I also want the menu to close. I tried this using `label` inside `label`, but it doesn't work.
My prototype code:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label span:hover {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.opener .menu {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  padding: 12px 4px;
  width: 270px;
}

#menu:checked~.opener .menu {
  display: none;
}

#menu~.opener>span:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

#menu:~.opener>span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
}

#menu:checked~.opener>span:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: block;
}

#menu:checked~.opener>span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#red:checked~.box {
  background-color: red;
}

#blue:checked~.box {
  background-color: blue;
}

#green:checked~.box {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input id="menu" type="checkbox"></input>
<input id="red" type="radio" name="opcoes" checked></input>
<input id="blue" type="radio" name="opcoes"></input>
<input id="green" type="radio" name="opcoes"></input>

<label class="opener" for="menu"><span>Open</span><span>Close</span>
      <div class="menu">
        <label for="red"><span>red</span></label>
<label for="blue"><span>blue</span></label>
<label for="green"><span>green</span></label>
</div>
</label>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Or you can check here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JxzPKR

Is there a way to close the menu when you click on one of the options without JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, contrary to popular opinion, it's just more dev friendly to use Javascript.

There is too much conditional logic for this to be a pure CSS solution. There are ~3 `if-then-else` conditions you would have to satisfy, while keeping the styles cascading. I think the most arduous task to satisfy is that you have a toggle header, in addition to other controls toggling it.

This will inherently get more complex and convoluted the more components you add. But here is an example using `:target`. This is a work-around and provides a solution to the question at hand. You won't be able to 'toggle' the menu this way so I had to add the header under the elements so it can be accessed via some kind of sibling selector:

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
a:any-link {
  all: unset;
}
.menu-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.menu-header a {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.menu-header .close {
  display: none;
}
#menu-body {
  display: none;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  background-color: rgba(220,220,220,1);
  height: 100px;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu-header a,
#menu-body label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-body:not(:target) {
  display: none;
}
#menu-body:not(:target) + .menu-header > a:not(.close) {
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu-body:target {
  display: flex;
}
#menu-body:target + .menu-header > a {
  display: none;
}
#menu-body:target + .menu-header > a.close {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">  
  
  <div id="menu-body">  
    <input id="red" type="radio" name="opcoes" checked/>
    <label for="red"><a href="#">Red</a></label>  
    <input id="blue" type="radio" name="opcoes"/>
    <label for="blue"><a href="#">Blue</a></label>
    <input id="green" type="radio" name="opcoes"/>  
    <label for="green"><a href="#">Green</a></label>
  </div>  
   
  <div class="menu-header"><a href="#menu-body">&equiv; Open</a><a href="#" class="close">&equiv; Close</a></div>   
</div>
```

You should consider accessability using this method, or at minimum, how this effects site navigation.

---

Edit: A demo in regards to discussion in comments:

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
a:any-link {
  all: unset;
}
#menu-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
#menu-header a {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
}
#menu-header .close {
  display: none;
}
#menu-body {
  display: none;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  background-color: rgba(220,220,220,1);
  height: 100px;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu-header a,
#menu-body label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-body:not(:target) {
  display: none;
}
#menu-body:not(:target) ~ .menu-header > a:not(.close) {
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu-body:target {
  display: flex;
}
#menu-body:target ~ #menu-header > a {
  display: none;
}
#menu-body:target ~ #menu-header > a.close {
  display: inline-block;
}

#red:target ~ .box {
  background-color: red;
}
#blue:target ~ .box {
  background-color: blue;
}
#green:target ~ .box {
  background-color: green;
}
.box {
  background-color: black;
  width: 75px; height : 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">  
  
  <input id="red" type="radio" name="opcoes" checked/>
  <input id="blue" type="radio" name="opcoes"/>
  <input id="green" type="radio" name="opcoes"/> 
    
  <div id="menu-body">  
    <a href="#red">Red</a>
    <a href="#blue">Blue</a>
    <a href="#green">Green</a>
  </div>  
   
  <div class="box"></div> 
  <div id="menu-header">
    <a href="#menu-body">&equiv; Open</a>
    <a href="#" class="close">&equiv; Close</a>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think about `:target` in this case. Also, you gave me more material to study. Thank you.

Comment: @Azametzin my answer is actually wrong taking a second look at it. This closes the menu, but it does not actually change the checked value. This won't be possible because click events can't be passed through elements, only `pointer-events: none` can be set in this circumstance so that the label can then switch it's respective `:checked` state, but that means the link will no longer be able to target another element. Give that you essentially have 3 toggle states, I'm not so sure this is possible

Comment: You can set the target to the input by it's color, for example `<a href="#red">` and that will change the boxes color, if you want an example of that I'll update my answer, but it won't change any input states @Azametzin

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the patience and time for clarification. No need to going too much further. I'm going to use JavaScript for now since I have not much time, but I will certainly study the possibilities presented here. Thank you again. @soulshined

Comment: great solution.